# Ubuntu on Asus F5Rseries Celeron M520

Tags: asus

Can Ubuntu run on Ubuntu on Asus F5Rseries Celeron M520 including sound and WiFi?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a hardware question.

Comment: I am wanting to learn if Ubuntu is compatible with this Asus laptop. Raphael's answer was very encouraging and helpful. It is a hardware question but more about the operating system being able to sit on it.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, but it is recommended to install a lighter version of Ubuntu as because your hardware seems a little old. It is recommended to install Lubuntu or Xubuntu for this kind of hardware.

And as is reported at [ARCH](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ASUS_F5R):

1. Sound should work out of the box.
2. There shouldn't be any problem with wifi but **IF** there is any problem, then the solution has been stated also at [ARCH](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_network_configuration#ndiswrapper).